# SQL query or Programmatic Filter for Big Data?

Tags: python, sql-server-2008, dictionary, bigdata

I am working with Python, fetching huge amounts of data from MS SQL Server Database and processing those for making graphs.

The real issue is that I wanted to know whether it would be a good idea to repeatedly perform queries to filter the data (using pyodbc for SQL queries) using attributes like WHERE and SELECT DISTINCT etc. in queries

OR

To fetch the data and use the list comprehensions, map and filter functionalities of python to filter the data in my code itself.

If I choose the former, there would be around 1k queries performed reducing significant load on my python code, otherwise if I choose the latter, I would be querying once and add on a bunch of functions to go through all the records I have fetched, more or less the same number of times(1k).

The thing is python is not purely functional, (if it was, I wouldnt be asking and would have finished and tested my work hundreds of times by now).

Which one would you people recommend?

For reference I am using Python 2.7. It would be highly appreciated if you could provide sources of information too. Also, Space is not an issue for fetching the whole data.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use one query with the modifiers you need?

Comment: Because I am filtering the data according to a list of specifications. So for each specification in the list, the data needs to be refined. 
You can imagine it to be as a collection of tree information. Now what I want is different trees and subtrees. So for each of the subtrees/trees there are different parent and children involved. Thats why.

Answer (score 0):

If you have bandwidth to burn, and prefer Python to SQL, go ahead and do one big query and filter in Python.

Otherwise, you're probably better off with multiple queries.

Sorry, no references here.  ^_^

Comment: Are there no significant advantages with any? I can do any of those.
I just want to know which method would you guys take if only performance is the bottleneck. To add on, the data increases everyday on the database.

Comment: I'd say the main difference is how much data gets transferred over the network.

Comment: so multiple queries should make it faster right since they cause filtered data transfer?

Comment: Yes, where clauses should minimize data transfer.